# org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Bad [Content_Types].xml

Tags: java, docx4j

Writing xml data into document using docx4j. Using below mentioned jars for this.

```
commons-compress-1.18 
commons-io-2.6 docx4j-core-8.1.5 
docx4j-JAXB-Internal-8.1.5 
docx4j-openxml-objects-8.1.5 
slf4j-api-1.7.26 
xalan-interpretive-8.0.0 
xalan-serializer-8.0.0
```

Java code used to write xml data into docx file.

```
public String fillXMLBasedForm(String documentForm, String xmlSchemaFilePath, String templateForm)
    throws Exception {

try {
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(templateForm));
    FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(xmlSchemaFilePath);
    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML);
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new FileOutputStream(new File(documentForm)), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return documentForm;
```

}

I am not facing any issue on local environment, but other users getting below exceptions.

```
    Caused by: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Bad [Content_Types].xml
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:867)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.get(Load3.java:146)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:834)
    ... 38 more


    javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 116 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Property rStyle appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.docx4j.wml.RPr
        at protected org.docx4j.wml.RPr org.docx4j.wml.R.rPr
        at org.docx4j.wml.R
        at protected java.util.List org.docx4j.wml.RunIns.customXmlOrSmartTagOrSdt
        at org.docx4j.wml.RunIns
        at protected java.util.List org.docx4j.wml.Body.content
        at org.docx4j.wml.Body
        at public org.docx4j.wml.Body org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory.createBody()
        at org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory
Property rFonts appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.docx4j.wml.RPr
        at protected org.docx4j.wml.RPr org.docx4j.wml.R.rPr
        at org.docx4j.wml.R
```

Comment: Weird.  If you can reproduce, please send me the docx and XML.

Comment: @JasonPlutext i can't share the docx and xml. here is some more input for you. For other user in Context class tempContext going through com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl to get the jaxb implementation but in mine case it is com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.